# How to sync remote github repository from one accoun to another remote repository created under second account

Tags: github, repository

I basically have two github private repositories in two different account and I want to set a provision in such way that when the code is pushed to first repository it should automatically available in (sync with) second repository created under different account.

I have referred https://github.com/makefu/repo-sync but didn't help.

Any one has steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the mirror GitHub repo is under a different account does not matter, as long as your process has the right credentials (username/password).

If you are alone working on that repo, you can simply [push to two different repos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43426524/6309), as long as your [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) has both credentials memorized.

If you are not alone, and your remote repo can be updated (push) from multiple sources, you need to register a [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), and setup a listener able to [push events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent).
You can find an example in `webhook.py` mentioned in [`RalfJung/git-mirror`](https://github.com/RalfJung/git-mirror).

The idea is to trigger a `git fetch repo1` + `git push --mirror repo2` in order to keep repo2 in sync with repo1.